# Use OpenAI Whisper API without local file

Tags: node.js, openai-api, node.js-fs, openai-whisper

I wanna use the Whisper API without having the path to the file being the path for a folder in my local computer (like shown in the official documentation):

```js
import fs from "fs";
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI();

async function main() {
  const transcription = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
    file: fs.createReadStream("audio.mp3"),
    model: "whisper-1",
  });

  console.log(transcription.text);
}
main();
```

That means I can't use `fs.createReadStream()`. However, I couldn't get any way for this to work, be it with Blob, Buffer, base64, anything.

How should I approach this? Whisper doesn't seem to accept anythind besides what `fs.createReadStream("file/path")` creates.

My file will be hosted on the computer of the user or elsewhere the web.